# How do we get complete file path with spaces in the directory name on shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I am monitoring a folder with inotify and on new files created on watched folder, I need to call php script with complete file path.

```
inotifywait -m -r /mnt/test -e create -e moved_to |
while read path action file; do
echo "$path"
echo "$path$file"
done
```

If I place a folder "New Folder" and a file inside "New Folder/test.jpg", The path only returns "/mnt/test/New" while I am expecting "/mnt/test/New File/". With this my result for $path$file is "/mnt/test/Newtest.jpg" while I am expecting "/mnt/test/New Folder/test.jpg"

Comment: try quoting it `"New Folder"` or try escaping the space `New\ Folder`

Comment: The users upload those folder. So I cannot manually add quotes like that.

Comment: `read` the input from the user using `read` or `args` and store it to any variable then just quote the variable like `"${userinput}`"